# PrintWriter to print on next line

Tags: java, sql, io, printwriter

I have the following code to print a string(from a ResultSet) to a text file:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(file, false));
while(RS.next()) {
    writer.write(RS.getString(1)+"\n");
}
```

I put a "\n" in the write statement in hopes that it will print each row on a different line, but it failed. The txt file currently prints out like so, with row# being a different row in the ResultSet:

row1row2row3row4row5

I want it to print out like:

row1

row2

row3

row4

row5

...

Comment: Try using `System.getProperty("file.separator")` instead of `\n` and see if that works. This will also mitigate platform dependency for newlines.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use [`println`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println%28java.lang.String%29) to print a newline character after each line:

```
writer.println(RS.getString(1));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**PrintWriter#println()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29) method instead.

From API:

> Terminates the current line by writing the line separator string. The
>   line separator string is defined by the system property
>   line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline character
>   ('\n').

Also this should work as well.

```
writer.write(RS.getString(1)+ System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use, in the statement. For example:

```
writer.print("1"+"<br/>");
writer.print("2"+"<br/>");
```